# How to bundle images within a .jar file?

Tags: java, image

Ok i'm having some problems with distributing my .jar file. When i just run the program from NetBeans it works, but if i try to run it from the dist folder it doesn't work (none of the images get loaded).

Here is the hierarchy of my program:

- src/img/*random images*
- src/myapp/*source files*

I load images with this function:

```
public BufferedImage getImg(String path) throws IOException {
    if (this.getClass().getResource(path) != null) {
        return ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(path));
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And after that:

```
BufferedImage image = getImg("../img/static_bg.png");
if (image != null) {
    g.drawImage(image, 309, 884, this);
}
```

After i build my project the images are in the jar file, but they aren't getting loaded. Any ideas why?

Comment: Oh sorry about that, fixed it.

Comment: `getImg("/img/static_bg.png");`

Comment: Oh god it was so simple. Thanks!!!

Comment: *"fixed it."*  Nice edit.  +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

To load a file from your war file in a web application, you will need to load it from the "ServletContext".    There is a `getServletContext()` method on every servlet that can be used for this purpose.  It can also be obtained from `request.getSession().getServletContext()`

```
URL url = servletContext.getResource(name);
if (url == null) return null;
URLConnection resourceConn = url.openConnection();
return ImageIO.read(resourceConn);
```